# Is there an efficient, general formula to verify if a number is a n-sided polygonal number?

Tags: number-theory, polygons

I've seen formulas to verify if a number is a triangular number, a pentagonal number, or a hexagonal number, but I haven't seen a general formula for verifying if a number is an n-sided polygonal number. Does such a formula exist?

Comment: [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygonal_number#Formula).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. The polygon number formula for the $n$th $r$-gonal number is $$\frac{n((r-2)n-(r-4))}{2}$$

Wolfram Mathworld has an article about it [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PolygonalNumber.html).